# Can log into Skype web but not into Skype on my PC... what's going on?

Tags: windows-7, skype, windows-live-messenger

I've recently installed Microsoft Windows Live Essentials 2012 and as a result of this it appears that the version of Skype I've installed has now been merged with my Microsoft MSN Messenger account or Microsoft Account.

I've even tried resetting my password. I am able to log in at http://web.skype.com/ but can no longer log into skype on my PC. Even if I reset my password, and click on the email to reset the password, I still cannot log in with my new password on Windows 7 (I can only log in via web browser).

My MSN accounts and skype accounts have been merged (but not my FB account).

What is happening?

Comment: You say you can no longer log in, but what actually happens when you try to log into the desktop version? Error message(s)?

Comment: Your MSN Messenger Account was merged with your Skype account ages ago, you might not have realized it, but MSN Messenger hasn't been supported for over 2 years now.

Comment: Fair enough. What I am seeing is that now when I try to log into skype both a Windows Live icon (the one with the four blue squares) as well a Facebook icon show up on the right-hand-side. I cannot log in with my skype account, nor with my Microsoft account. What should i do?

Comment: What version of Skype are you using.  If you are not using the current version start by upgrading to it.  Just to be clear the option, to log into your Skype account is simply missing, is that correct?

Comment: The login screen doesn't show me the version, but it must be the latest since I've seen the software being updated today. The Microsoft login subscreen has the following at the bottom: (c) 2015, so it can't be that old.

Answer (score 0):

Over Web browser of course it will connect, but over messenger it will not.
the reason: You must delete "`shared.xml`" file in "C:\Users(USER NAME)\AppData\Local" and then try to enter your new reseted account password in your Skype application.